# Parsing HTTP data in C using MCU

Tags: c++, c, nodemcu

I am trying to parse the data obtained from GET / POST request using C in a MCU based project. I must say upfront that I haven't work with c and c++ for some time, so any suggestion is welcome.

So, the data arriving the MCU has the following markup:

```
HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic blablah
Content-Type: application/json
{
redLedBrightness:50,
redLedIsOn:true,
greenLedBrightness:70,
greenLedIsOn:false,
}
```

where the end beginnning of the lines are given respectively by `\r` and `\n`.
My approach entailed processing line by line, and searching the corresponding key (e.g. `Authorization` or `redLedBrightness`) and its value (e.g. `blahblah` or `50`). I wrote the following code, which seemed to be working fine in the compiler I was using, but not in the MCU.

One of problems seems to be in the statement `*tempInDataP = *index;` since the MCU stops hanging if I comment it out. Of course I need this line, but I cannot figure out where the problem(s) is (are). I suspect the compiler I am using is not showing all the errors.

Here is an adaption of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#define IN_DATA_SIZE 100
#define TEMP_IN_DATA_SIZE 10
using namespace std;
char mock[] = "Authentication:YERL90,\r\nredLedBri:400,\r\nredLedOn:true\r\n";
char * mockP = mock;

char inData[IN_DATA_SIZE];
char * inDataP = inData;
char tempInData[TEMP_IN_DATA_SIZE];
char * tempInDataP = tempInData;
const char * auth = "YERL90";
bool isAuthenticated = false;

void printBuffer(char * buf) {
    for (char *p = buf; *p; p++) {
        cout << *p;
    }
}

void resetBuffer(char * buf, int _size)
{
  memset(buf, 0, _size);
}

/**
 * Returns true if keyWord exists and update the variable tempInData
 * with the response / value
 */
bool parseResponse(char * res, const char * keyWord, int dataShift ) {
  cout << "\nParsing:" << res << endl;
  char * index;

  // Reset temp in data buffer and its pointer
  resetBuffer(tempInData, TEMP_IN_DATA_SIZE);
  tempInDataP = &tempInData[0];

  // Search for a member /keyword inside the response
  index = strstr(res, keyWord);

  if (index) {
      // Keyword exists in the response
      // Move the index to the beginning of the value (key:value)
    index = index + strlen(keyWord) + dataShift;
    while ((*index != '\r') && (*index != ',')) {
      *tempInDataP = *index;
      tempInDataP++;
      index++;
    }

    // Terminate the string with a null
    *tempInDataP = '\0';
    return true;
  } else {
      cout << "-bul" << endl;
      //Object was not found
    return false;
  }
}


bool checkAuth(const char * _auth) {
    if (strcmp (auth, _auth) == 0) 
        return true;
     else 
        return false;
}


int main()
{
    while(*mockP) {
    // Simulating, reading data from the channel
    *inDataP=*mockP;
    //Parsing line by line
    if (*inDataP == '\n') {
        //Check for authentication if not done yet
        if(!isAuthenticated) {
            cout << "Authenticating ..." << endl;
            if(parseResponse(inData, "Authentication", 1)) {
                cout << "Key exists ..." << endl;
                if(checkAuth(tempInData)) {
                    cout << "Correct Password" << endl;
                    isAuthenticated = true;
                } else {
                  cout << "Password Invalid" << endl;
                  // Prepare headers
                  // Send response with unauthorized access
                  // stop connection
                  break;
                } 
            } else {
                cout << "Data not found" << endl;
            }
        } else {
            // User is logged in
            cout << "User is logged in" << endl;
            if(parseResponse(inData, "redLedBri", 1)) {
               cout << "Data exists:" << tempInData << endl;
               // update local variables
            } else {
                cout << "Data not found" << endl;
            }

        }
        resetBuffer(inData, IN_DATA_SIZE);
        inDataP = &inData[0];
    }  
    else {
       inDataP++;
    }
    mockP++;
    } 

    //close connection and log the user out

   return 0;
}
```

I am open for other alternatives, as this implementation seems a bit cumbersome depending on the JSON file sent to the MCU.

Comment: If the protocol used is HTTP 1.1, you *must* support chunked encoding. It's a protocol requirement. Your query should not claim HTTP 1.1 support unless you support all HTTP 1.1 protocol requirements and you should not get an HTTP 1.1 response unless you claim HTTP 1.1 support in your query.

Comment: If you want to support HTTP 1.1 and JSON, I strongly urge you to find an HTTP 1.1 implementation and a JSON implementation that meet your requirements. Trying to implement just what you think you need and claiming you implemented HTTP 1.1 and JSON is a very, very bad idea that has caused much pain in the past.

Comment: One trick I use when coding for MCUs where the debugging facilities are usually not as good as what I can get on a PC is to do most of the development on the PC. I can knock out the gross logic errors where I can poke and prod and easily debug and that leaves me with the nitty-gritty stuff to pick off the hard way on the MCU. Usually a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

I see potential buffer overruns.  You trust your input too much.  You assume it will end with '\r' or ',' characters, and if it doesn't then you will overrun the bounds of your array(s) and access arbitrary memory.

At the very least, pass the maximum length with each array pointer, and check in each loop iteration that you NEVER access an element beyond the last address of the array.

Comment: The length of the pointer is dynamic, I cannot know in advance. The only delimiters that I have at hand are the '\r' and '\n'.

Comment: @vtolentino That's why he's asking you to pass it along. You know how many bytes you received, I hope. If not, your receiving code is badly broken.